# Score for ellipsoid fitting

Tags: geometry

I have implemented a least-square ellipsoid fitting algorithm for magnetometer calibration. Now I want to have a metric on the collected 3D points to tell the user whether sufficient data has been collected to produce good calibration parameters.

Are there any established metrics for this?

The only idea I came up with was something based on spread of azimuth and elevation of the collected points, which should ideally completely cover the ellipsoid.

However, this may fail if the ellipsoid has a high eccentricity and/or its origin displacement is large compared to its size...

Comment: You could use a [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test).

Comment: It might be useful to apply a linear transform to the data such that the best fit ellipsoid is mapped to the unit sphere. It would potentially make computing $\chi^2$ or using some other test easier due to symmetry.

Comment: I may be a bit confused. I am familiar with the chi-squared test to test if the points were drawn from a standard normal distribution. However, in the problem above, the uncalibrated points are not all inside a specific ellipsoid (which can be mapped to the unit sphere via the estimated ellipsoid parameters), but rather on the surface of the ellipsoid. How could I apply chi-square testing to see if the surface is sufficiently covered by the recorded points?